# Cannot Change backgound image using javascript though the image change is shown in console?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, background-image

hello people i am trying to change background images on a interval of 3 seconds using javascript the code seem to be correct because the images can be seen changed in the console
but not on the screen i see blank screen after 3 seconds.

here is my react code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Home() {
  let i = 0; // Start index from 0

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(backgroundImages, 3000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval); // Clean up the interval when the component unmounts
    };
  }, []);

  function backgroundImages() {
    const imagearr = [
      "rajwada.jpeg",
      "indore.jpeg",
      "females.jpeg",
      "mayor.jpg"

    ]


    console.log("Changing background image");
    document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = `url(${imagearr[i]})`;
    i++;
    if (i === imagearr.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }


  return (
    <div className="PARENTHERO">

      <div className="Hero" id="main" >
        {/* <div className="WELCOME">
        <h1 className="Heading2">LUCKY DRAW</h1>
        <h1 className="Heading2"> NAGAR PALIKA NIGAM INDORE</h1>
        </div> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

here are my css classes

```
.Hero {
    background-image: url(mayor.jpg);
    height: 60vh;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}

.PARENTHERO {
    height: 100%;
}
```

by default i am using an image in the background also consider the names of the images to be correct and no path issues

Comment: seems odd you would be using DOM and not just using an inline style and set it with a variable.

Comment: Your styles are not being applied. `className="..."` should be `class="..."`

Comment: ...Maybe. If this HTML is within a JSX I believe you should continue to use `className`. However, the fact that your image is not rendering but you are seing the console log suggests that the script is working but the style is not applied. Put some content in the "Hero" so that it is held open so you can prove this.

Comment: You know what I can see In  the console that the styles are applied in element.style don't know why eventually it do not render

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code in my next js demo project and it worked fine for me, Although i did some changes

1. Defined a constant for 'main', Due to this error ( i think it is due to TS ) [image]
2. Used my own images.
3. Also I have used relative path in css file [image]

```
  let i = 0; // Start index from 0

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(backgroundImages, 3000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval); // Clean up the interval when the component unmounts
    };
  }, []);

  function backgroundImages() {
    const imagearr = [
      "Gojo-3.jpg",
      "gojo-2.jpg",
      "Gojo-1.jpeg",
    ]

    console.log("Changing background image");

    // Changes start
    const ele = document.getElementById("main")
    if(ele){
      ele.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imagearr[i]})`;
    }
    // Changes End

    i++;
    if (i === imagearr.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct but I think you haven't imported the images which you want to use in the animation.
Please try again after importing respective images and let me know what happens.